# Application "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild" could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I'm trying to import a bunch of Eclipse Java projects into a workspace (called "TestWorkSpace") and I want to do this via batch script. I'm running into a bit of an issue:

**Error shown in .metadata/.log**

```
!SESSION 2014-08-05 09:18:58.272 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll /trunk
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -data testworkspace -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll /trunk

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-08-05 09:19:03.240
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

**Command Used in batch script**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\eclipsec.exe" -data testworkspace -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll /trunk
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild` is part of Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools - do you have that installed?

Comment: I do not. Does it still apply if I want to import Java projects?

Comment: That import tool is provided by Eclipse CDT, so if you don't have that installed it does not exist. I don't know if it works for Java projects. The core Eclipse does not have a headless import tool.

Comment: Is there anything similar for importing Java/Android projects through commandline?

Comment: I don't know about android, Java does not have anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild` application is part of the Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools (CDT), so you need to have that installed in order to use this application.

Neither the core Eclipse nor the Java Development Tools has a headless import tool.

You can import multiple existing projects using the 'File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace' tool - but that requires using the Eclipse GUI.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the GUI. Thanks for your input though